# Is there a way to see the real p-value, as R shows me a 0?

Tags: p-value

I am running Bartlett test on R and it's resulting me a p-value = 0. What does that mean? Can I actually see the real value? I am a novice in the software, so it's probably something quite simple.

Comment: If you're willing to use Python, you can perform the test with `scipy.stats.bartlett` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bartlett.html), and it will display the actual p-value unless it's too small to be distinguished from 0 with double precision floats (<1e-308 or so). If you post your data, I can send complete code that you can run on Google Colab.